# Save output from interrupted loop / *ply

Tags: r, dplyr

I sometimes have lengthy *ply loops in R where for example an API gets called in each iteration.

I am wondering if it is possible to *manually* interrupt a *ply function after it has been started, while the return of the last completed iteration is still saved.

When i use a for loop and construct an empty object beforehand, where i attach the return of the loop in every iteration to the same object, i have such a partial return in the case of a manual interrupt. I am wondering if this would be possible for the *ply family of functions.

I know that the better way to do this is check the loop with a small number of iterations first and then let it run in the complete set. Another way would be to use `tryCatch()` or a `foreach()` loop with `.errorhandling="pass"` to avoid an interrupted loop from bad returns. I am looking for a way for manual interruption, though.

Right now i use the `save()` function to write to disk, but this slows things massively down and is therefore not feasible. I would assume it is possible to write to a previously created environment by `assign()`, but that is also a bit hackish and could lead to bad overwrites.

The optimal thing would be if someone knows a way to do this with dplyr's `do()`.

Comment: I don't think this is possible as functions do not work in such a manner to provide a partial output but would be interesting to be proven wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that by *ply you mean the `apply` family (apply, sapply, lapply, tapply, etc.). If not, I am sorry.

Still, I think that you can easily achieve what you want with the `<<-` operator. It will impact your performance, though.

```
# Let's assume that your loop output is computed by this function :
> do.some.stuff <- function(p) {
+     p
+ }
# If we want to save the last output…
> ret <- sapply(1:100000,function(x) {
+     to.save <<- do.some.stuff(x)
+     to.save
+ })
> to.save
[1] 100000
# If we want to save all the computed outputs…
> to.save <- vector()
> ret <- sapply(1:100000,function(x) {
+     ret <- do.some.stuff(x)
+      to.save <<- c(to.save, ret)
+      ret
+ })
^C  # <-- manual interruption
> str(to.save)
 int [1:21753] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...


# Example for dplyr and do():
library(dplyr)
system.time({
      to.save <- vector()
      final.ret <- sample_n(iris,10e4,replace=T) %>% rowwise %>% do(w_mean={
        ret <- round(.$Sepal.Width,digits=1)
        to.save <<- c(placeholder,out)
        ret
      })
})
# Commenting out the assignment saves about 80 seconds for me.
```

The impact on the performance is quite important, though. Besides, it is not a natural way of using an `apply` function. Maybe `for` is the answer here.

Comment: 3 years of R and i never knew about `<<-`... thank you very much, it works perfectly. To clarify, i also meant the **ply functions from plyr or mapping functions like `do` from dplyr. And your approach works there as well! I will add an example to your answer.